# How do make 4 divs group together and display side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner 
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra  
.awpcp-listing-primary-image-thumbnail 
.awpcp-listing-excerpt-content
```

Together, they create an advert on my site.

The problem is, how do I get them to display side by side in desktop view.

Aside from wrapping them in a media query for desktop, I've tried

```
{ display: inline-block;} 
{display: inline-block; float: left;
```

This has the undesired effect of not grouping the divs together and displaying each group side by side, but dividing the advert into three separate sections: photo on the left, text in the middle, extra info on the right.

Is there some html or css which would place each ad,  or group, side by side?

I have this html which apparently controls page layout:

```
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt $awpcpdisplayaditems 
$isfeaturedclass" data-breakpoints-class-prefix="awpcp- 
listing-excerpt" data-breakpoints='{"tiny": [0,328], "small": 
[328,600], "medium": [600,999999]}'>
<div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-thumbnail">
$awpcp_image_name_srccode
 </div>
 <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-inner" style="w">
  <h4 class="awpcp-listing-title">$title_link</h4>
  <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt- 
   content">$excerpt</div>
    </div>
    <div class="awpcp-listing-excerpt-extra">
    $awpcpadpostdate
    $awpcp_city_display
    $awpcp_state_display
    $awpcp_display_adviews
    $awpcp_display_price
    $awpcpextrafields
    </div>
   <span class="fixfloat"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="fixfloat"></div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete code example of the HTML elements in question, along with all CSS rules that apply to them? Be sure to include CSS rules that are applied globally to tags (e.g. 'img', 'div') that might be influencing their styling

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler is the page link. I'm not sure where to find the css you asked for other than in view-source. Mostly it's controlled and manipulated through siteorigin, not additional css box.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? They're responsive aswell.

```css
.about-section {
    max-width: 1280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.about-section h3 {
    color: #333;
    margin: 90px 0 60px 0;
}


.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 22%;
    max-width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
    float: left;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    margin-left: 4%;
}    

#firstBox{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-section" id="about">

    <h3>About us</h3>

    <div class="box" id="firstBox">

        <p>Box one</p>

    </div>

    <div class="box">

        <p>Box two</p>

    </div>

    <div class="box">

        <p>Box three</p>

    </div>

    <div class="box">

        <p>Box four</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The css didn't do anything. Feel free to view page: https://adsler.co.uk/browse-adsler/ to get a better idea, view on desktop.

Comment: You gave each div the width of 1324px. Normal that the others can't fit side by side

Comment: Oh, how do I get out of that one then please?

Comment: Do i insert html and CSS or just one?